# Does Slack support formatting with Markdown?

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

I am seeing this in Slack:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

My Node.js code just looks like this:

```
  const messageText = `

   ## Jenkins build started

   ## Build status: ${b.state}

   #### Repo: ${b.repo_name || 'unknown repo'}

   Raw data:
   \`\`\`
   ${JSON.stringify(b)}
   \`\`\`

  `;

  // "type": "mrkdwn",


  return webClient.chat.postMessage({channel: id, text:  messageText, mrkdwn: true}).then(res => {
      console.log('Message sent: ', res.ts);
    });
```

Obviously slack is getting the request, it's just not formatted how I would expect, anybody know how to format markdown nicely on Slack?

Answer (score 1):

Slack does not support Markdown, but has its own markup language.

Example:

> ```
> _italic_ will produce italicized text
> *bold* will produce bold text
> ~strike~ will produce strikethrough text
> ```

Its not possible to produce headings.

Check out the offical documentation [here](https://api.slack.com/messaging/composing/formatting#basics) for a complete description of all options.